# Unable to show the tooltip of individual chart inside individual div using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    .area {
      stroke-width: 0;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    #one {
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    }
    #two {
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #0000FF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <script>
    var myData = "date New York San Francisco Austin\n\
20111001 63.4 62.7 72.2\n\
20111002 58.0 59.9 67.7\n\
20111003 53.3 59.1 69.4\n\
20111004 55.7 58.8 68.0\n\
20111005 64.2 58.7 72.4\n\
20111006 58.8 57.0 77.0\n\
20111007 57.9 56.7 82.3\n\
20111008 61.8 56.8 78.9\n\
20111009 69.3 56.7 68.8\n\
20111010 71.2 60.1 68.7\n\
20111011 68.7 61.1 70.3\n\
20111012 61.8 61.5 75.3\n\
20111013 63.0 64.3 76.6\n\
20111014 66.9 67.1 66.6\n\
20111015 61.7 64.6 68.0\n\
20111016 61.8 61.6 70.6\n\
20111017 62.8 61.1 71.1\n\
20111018 60.8 59.2 70.0\n\
20111019 62.1 58.9 61.6\n\
20111020 65.1 57.2 57.4\n\
20111021 55.6 56.4 64.3\n\
20111022 54.4 60.7 72.4\n";

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("basis")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.temperature);
      });

    var svg = d3.select("#one").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var data = d3.tsv.parse(myData);

    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key !== "date";
    }));

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: +d[name]
          };
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) {
          return v.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);

    var legend = svg.selectAll('g')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend');

    legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', width - 20)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
      })
      .attr('width', 10)
      .attr('height', 10)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    legend.append('text')
      .attr('x', width - 8)
      .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return (i * 20) + 9;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Temperature (ºF)");

    var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      });

    city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          name: d.name,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
      });

    var mouseG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-over-effects");

    mouseG.append("path")
      .attr("class", "mouse-line")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    var lines = document.getElementsByClassName('line');

    var mousePerLine = mouseG.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "mouse-per-line");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data([cities])
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width / 2)
      .attr("height", height / 3)
      .style("padding", "5px")
      .style("stroke", "#272525")
      .style("fill", "#272525")
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0")
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('y', -45);

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.innerRect')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("class", "innerRect");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "1px")
      .style("opacity", "0");

    mousePerLine.append("text")
      .attr("class", "DateText");

    mousePerLine.selectAll('.mouse-per-line')
      .data(cities)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "ValueText")
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .style("font-size", "10pt");

    mouseG.append('svg:rect')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line innerRect")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "0");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "0");
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() {
        d3.select(".mouse-line")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line rect")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line innerRect")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line circle")
          .style("opacity", "1");
        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line text")
          .style("opacity", "1");
      })

    .on('mousemove', function() {

      var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
      console.log(mouse);
      d3.select(".mouse-line")
        .attr("d", function() {
          var d = "M" + mouse[0] + "," + height;
          d += " " + mouse[0] + "," + 0;
          return d;
        });

      if (mouse[0] >= (width * (2 / 3))) {

        console.log(mouse);

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]);
            var bisect;
            var xDateValue = /\w*.\s.\d.\d*.\d*.:\d*.:\d*/.exec(xDate);
            d3.selectAll('circle')
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                  return d.xDate;
                }).right;
                idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

                var beginning = 0,
                  end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                  target = null;

                while (true) {
                  target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                  pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                  if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                    break;
                  }
                  if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                  else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                  else break;
                }
                return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
              });

            d3.select(this)
              .select('rect')
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0] - (width / 1.8)) + "," + (height / 2) + ")";
              });

            d3.select(this)
              .selectAll('.innerRect')
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0] - (width / 2)) + "," + ((height / 2) + 45 - (i * 20)) + ")";
              })
              .attr('width', 10)
              .attr('height', 10)
              .attr("dx", '20px')
              .attr("dy", '0px')
              .style('fill', function(d) {
                return color(d.name);
              });

            d3.select(this)
              .select(".DateText")
              .text(xDateValue)
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0] - (width / 2) - 20) + "," + ((height / 2) - 10 - (i * 10)) + ")";
              })
              .attr("dx", '20px')
              .style("fill", "white")
              .style("font-weight", "bold")
              .style("font-size", "10pt");

            d3.select(this)
              .selectAll('.ValueText')
              .text(function(d, i) {
                return d.name + "  " + y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2);
              })
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0] - (width / 2)) + "," + ((height / 2) + 55 - (i * 20)) + ")";
              })
              .attr("dx", '20px');

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      } else {

        console.log("less than");

        d3.selectAll(".mouse-per-line")
          .attr("foo", function(d, i) {
            var xDate = x.invert(mouse[0]);
            var bisect;
            var xDateValue = /\w*.\s.\d.\d*.\d*.:\d*.:\d*/.exec(xDate);

            d3.selectAll('circle')
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) {
                  return d.xDate;
                }).right;
                idx = bisect(d.values, xDate);

                var beginning = 0,
                  end = lines[i].getTotalLength(),
                  target = null;

                while (true) {
                  target = Math.floor((beginning + end) / 2);
                  pos = lines[i].getPointAtLength(target);
                  if ((target === end || target === beginning) && pos.x !== mouse[0]) {
                    break;
                  }
                  if (pos.x > mouse[0]) end = target;
                  else if (pos.x < mouse[0]) beginning = target;
                  else break;
                }
                return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
              });

            d3.select(this)
              .select('rect')
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0]) + "," + (height / 2) + ")";
              });

            d3.select(this)
              .selectAll('.innerRect')
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0] + 15) + "," + ((height / 2) + 45 - (i * 20)) + ")";
              })
              .attr('width', 10)
              .attr('height', 10)
              .attr("dx", '20px')
              .attr("dy", '0px')
              .style('fill', function(d) {
                return color(d.name);
              });

            d3.select(this)
              .select(".DateText")
              .text(xDateValue)
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0] - 5) + "," + ((height / 2) - 10 - (i * 10)) + ")";
              })
              .attr("dx", '20px')
              .style("fill", "white")
              .style("font-weight", "bold")
              .style("font-size", "10pt");

            d3.select(this)
              .selectAll('.ValueText')
              .text(function(d, i) {
                return d.name + "  " + y.invert(pos.y).toFixed(2);
              })
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(" + (mouse[0] + 20) + "," + ((height / 2) + 55 - (i * 20)) + ")";
              })
              .attr("dx", '20px');

            return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + pos.y + ")";
          });
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Till now I am able to show the tooltip for this line graph inside div "one". But when I show another area graph inside second div "two"[image: the tooltips in different div are getting same mouse over coordinates and only the tooltip of second div is getting displayed], the tooltip data of first div goes off. Also, when I hover the mouse in first div the mouse starts moving and pointing in second div and the data of second div is displayed in both the div. How to solve this thing. How to display the tooltip of different charts in individual divs. Please help me.

Comment: Please, any tips/ suggestions of how to rectify this problem. When I hover mouse inside first div the second div responds along with the first div. The tooltip of first div is not visible but only the tooltip data of second div is visible in both the divs. Why is this happening?? Why the mouse responds in both the div at a time. Please help me

Comment: I didn't look through the complete code but the reason could be the following:

Comment: If an element already has a specific listener for an event (e.g. Mouseover) another one will remove the first one. The solution to this is adding an optional namespace (e.g. ...on('mouseover.tooltip1') and on ('mouse over.tooltip2', ....)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Rest of the code follows the same pattern as above for the second div. Let, me try your logic.

Comment: Sorry. I tried your logic but same issue. Please suggest any other comments / tips.

Comment: Please help me. How to make D3 'mousemove' and 'mouseover' properties 'div' specific? I am stuck. What am I doing wrong in my above codes that the mouse move responds equally at a time in all divs in my window.

Comment: Can you post the code which doesn't work? The code you posted is working fine...

Comment: The code is very large. I can't post whole of my code in Stack overflow. I don't know how to attach whole code file in stack overflow. I am sorry. I am afraid.